# R - Regex to Remove Last Word from String

Tags: regex, r

I have data like below -

```
PLAYSTORE BANGKOK
FLOAT@THE BAY          SINGAPORE
YANTRA                 SINGAPORE
AIRASIA_QS9DQQL        SINGAPORE
```

I want to remove the last word from each string, if it is in list of cities that i am looking for using this -

```
sub('(?i)^(.*)\\b(singapore|stockholm|singapor|bangkok|kuala lumpur|london|tokyo)$','\\2', merch_desc$desc2 )
```

But \1 or \2 dont work and i get the full string again. Is there a way to correct this?

I want 2 outputs - 1 with the company names and another with the locations into 2 separate vectors.

merch_desc$merch -

```
  PLAYSTORE 
    FLOAT@THE BAY          
    YANTRA                 
    AIRASIA_QS9DQQL
```

merch_desc$loc -

```
BANGKOK
SINGAPORE
SINGAPORE
SINGAPORE
```

It seems strange that it works on string but not on data frames -

```
test$desc2
[1] "qoo10                  singapore    " "bill payment via internet banking"    "mcdonald's restaurants singapore    "
[4] "hdb season parking     singapore    " "grabtaxi pte ltd       singapore    "
```

This does not work -

```
sub('^.* (singapore|stockholm|singapor|bangkok|kuala lumpur|london|tokyo)$', '\\1', test$desc2 )
[1] "qoo10                  singapore    " "bill payment via internet banking"    "mcdonald's restaurants singapore    "
[4] "hdb season parking     singapore    " "grabtaxi pte ltd       singapore    "
```

But this works -

```
sub('^.* (singapore|stockholm|singapor|bangkok|kuala lumpur|london|tokyo)$', '\\1', 'tigerair y843km singapore' )
[1] "singapore"
```

Edit 2 -

Use trimws(). Without Trimws it does not handle the multiple spaces.

Thanks,
Manish

Comment: What is the expected output?.  Try `sub('(.*)\\s+\\S+$', '\\1', str1)`

Comment: Added the answers. I want to match the city/country names and if matched then split the string. else keep it as is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can capture the substring as groups using `sub` in `pattern`, then we add a delimiter (`,`) between the capture groups in the `replacement`, use that as `sep` in the `read.table`.  If there are leading/lagging spaces, remove it by `str_trim` from `stringr` by looping through the columns.

```
library(stringr)
d1 <- read.table(text=sub('(.*)\\s+(\\S+)$', '\\1,\\2', v1),sep=',')
d1[] <- lapply(d1, str_trim)
d1
#              V1        V2
#1       PLAYSTORE   BANGKOK
#2   FLOAT@THE BAY SINGAPORE
#3          YANTRA SINGAPORE
#4 AIRASIA_QS9DQQL SINGAPORE
```

Or as suggested by @RichardScriven, a `base R` option for trimming leading/lagging spaces is `trimws`.

```
d1[] <- lapply(d1, trimws)
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c('PLAYSTORE BANGKOK','FLOAT@THE BAY          SINGAPORE',
       'YANTRA                 SINGAPORE',
        'AIRASIA_QS9DQQL        SINGAPORE')
```

Comment: > new = read.table(text=sub('(.*)\\s+(singapore|stockholm|singapor|bangkok|kuala lumpur|london|tokyo)$', '\\1~\\2', merch_desc$desc2),sep='~')
Warning message:
In scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  :
  EOF within quoted string
> View(new) - Has only 1 column instead of 2 columns

Comment: i tried with list of cities as i dont want any word to go into the 2nd column

Comment: `trimws()` is now in base R for trimming white space

Comment: I see this working, but not when i use this in a data frames. Can i not provide a data frame as i/p and map the o/p to a new column in the same data frame